# 0 rows appearing after querying a bigquery table with repeated column

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I queried a bigquery table which has field called **tags** which is string repeated.

```
select tags from table
```

result looks like below

```
tags
----
0 rows
```

Usually we do see null for an empty cell, here it's bit strange. Why is it so, cannot find this in bigquery documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery, when you query a repeated field like tags, if there are no values in that field for a particular row, it will not return **NULL**. Instead, it will return an **empty array []**. This behavior is consistent with the SQL standard for handling arrays and repeated fields.

So, in your case, if you're seeing tags as an empty array [], it indicates that there are no values present for the tags field in those rows, rather than it being NULL. This is normal behavior in BigQuery and is consistent with how repeated fields are handled.